# JS - can't change color but can change display property

Tags: javascript

Not sure why this isn't working. This is the rendered HTML:

```
<h2 id="step-3-question">...and for how much?</h2>
```

So just in the console, I'm running:

```
$('#step-3-question')[0].style.display = "none"
```

Which works fine, so the element is being found, BUT these do not have any effect:

```
$('#step-3-question')[0].style.color = "white"
$('#step-3-question')[0].style.color = "#000000"
```

Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? This should work just fine. (Keep in mind that "#000000" is black, not white)

Comment: $('#step-3-question').css('color','#000000'); though its not white color its may be black . for white you can use $('#step-3-question').css('color','#fff');

Comment: Actually, this is working perfectly http://jsbin.com/karugasewe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I agree with @Erik, I just tried it on my console and setting style.color to white works (you can even try on this stack overflow page - I used the html element with id = content)

Comment: ok i don't know what to say... inexplicably it's only not working on my one site. so i can't make a fiddle apparently because it will work fine! anyone stumble across something like this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the javascript that you have there is fine (for the chrome console, at the very least, and on a website, providing jquery is included)

My guess would be that perhaps something is overwriting the styles, on your page, perhaps with an `!important` directive.

Does: `$('#step-3-question')[0].style.color = "#000000 !important"` work?

***Note:*** If so, using `!important` in js would not be the solution, it would be better to find the offending css, and remove it.

Comment: YES! I found an extra `!important` somewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#step-3-question')[0].style.color = "white"
```

first apply style on font like white after

```
$('#step-3-question')[0].style.color = "#000000"
```

apply style on font like black so no changes also, code work fine.